# Flexible instances needed?

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I want to write a Convertible instance for a Haskell type to its C representation

It looks like this:

```
instance Convertible Variable (IO (Ptr ())) where
```

Now GHC complains:

```
 Illegal instance declaration for `Convertible
                                    Variable (IO (Ptr ()))'
  (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
   where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
   and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
   Use -XFlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
In the instance declaration for `Convertible Variable (IO (Ptr ()))'
```

I thought Flexible Instances were needed if you had free types in your instance declaration, but this is not the case. I can get it to compile when adding the right pragma, but can anyone explain why I need this?

Comment: because this "All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an) where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*" is the standard (Haskell 2010). If you need things that go beyond the standard, you must use extensions.

Comment: seems to me that Variable and  (IO (Ptr ())) are distinct?

Comment: Sure they are distinct, but neither `()` nor `Ptr ()` nor `IO (Ptr ())` are type **variables**

Comment: FWIW, `FlexibleInstances` is one of the most harmless language extensions that exist. Just enable it.

Comment: @kosmikus I feel like there should be a list of the most common extensions and their level of harmlessness somewhere. As a beginner, I feel weirded out every time GHC asks me to turn an extension on. EDIT: Apparently there is! Courtesy of supki in #haskell: [List of extensions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845179/which-haskell-ghc-extensions-should-users-use-avoid/10849782#10849782)

Comment: @kqr Well, I certainly have my own list :) The list you quote is at least problematic because it lists extensions that are difficult to implement and still changing even today such as `TypeFamilies` on the same level as utter trivialities such as `EmptyDataDecls`. Both might be good extensions, but if you're concerned about bitrot and stability, that's unfortunately not the only concern.

Comment: @kosmikus Would you mind jotting that list down and sharing it with me (and others?)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes you need flexible instances. Without it, all of your typeclass instance would have to look like

```
instance Foo (Maybe a) where
instance Foo (IO a)    where
instance Foo (Either a b) where
```

If you want to do anything other than `TypeConstructor a1 a2 a3 ...` (and `a`s have to be type variables) than you need flexible instances. But it's one of the most common language extensions, don't sweat using it.

Answer (score 5):

You can often avoid `FlexibleInstances` in cases like this. There are two general approaches:

#### Use an auxiliary class

```
instance ConvIO a => Convertible Variable (IO a) where
  method = methodIO

class ConvIO p where
  methodIO :: ...
  -- similar to the signature for the Convertible method,
  -- but with Variable and IO baked in

instance ConvIOPtr u => ConvIO (Ptr u) where
   methodIO = methodIOPtr

class ConvIOPtr u where
   methodIOPtr :: ...

instance ConvIOPtr () where ...
```

This approach works well when you need several instances headed by the same constructor.

#### Use an equality constraint

Turn on `GADTs` or `TypeFamilies` and write

```
instance a ~ Ptr () => Convertible Variable (IO a) where ...
```

This approach tends to help a lot with type inference, but only makes sense if you only need one instance headed by `IO`.

#### You can mix and match

You can use an auxiliary class to go through `IO`, and then an equality constraint to go through `Ptr`.

```
instance u ~ () => ConvIO (Ptr u) where ...
```

Or you can use an equality constraint to go through `IO` and an auxiliary class to go through `Ptr`:

```
instance (a ~ Ptr u, ConvIOPtr u) => Convertible Variable (IO a)
```

#### Where these won't work

If you need an instance one of whose arguments is a type variable, then you really can't avoid `FlexibleInstances` at all. You might be able to work around the problem using a newtype, but it's not worth the trouble.