# How to impose type constraints on typeclass instances?

Tags: haskell

I'm learning Haskell by reading [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/). Near the end of the [Making Our Own Types and Typeclasses](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) section, a class `YesNo` is defined to simulate truthiness in languages like javascript:

```hs
class YesNo a where  
    yesno :: a -> Bool 

instance YesNo Int where  
    yesno 0 = False  
    yesno _ = True  

(etc.)
```

I was trying to flesh out the instances myself as an exercise before reading the reference, and thought I could be clever and define it for all `Num` types:

```hs
instance (Num a) => YesNo a where
  yesno 0 = False
  yesno _ = True
```

I'll skip over how this requires [`FlexibleInstances`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/instances.html#extension-FlexibleInstances), which I think I've understood between the docs and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20147827/12162258). Once that's turned on, the compiler complains "The constraint 'Num a' is no smaller than the instance head 'YesNo a'". The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7198907/12162258) do a good job of explaining what that means. Using the `newtype` solution provided there, I come up with something like

```hs
newtype TruthyNum a = TruthyNum a

instance (Num a, Eq a) => YesNo (TruthyNum a) where
  yesno (TruthyNum 0) = False
  yesno _ = True
```

But now I have to say e.g. `yesno $ TruthyNum 0` instead of `yesno 0`.

This doesn't feel right. Is there really no way to cleanly express `yesno` for `Num` types without writing out an instance for each such type? Or, taking a step back, how would an experienced Haskell hacker come at the premise of "define a typeclass that implements truthiness in the vein of [pick your scripting language]"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very good question! I would exactly define a `newtype` like you did. I would not use it directly, rather I derive via it.

```
{-# Language DerivingVia              #-}
{-# Language StandaloneDeriving       #-}
{-# Language StandaloneKindSignatures #-}

import Data.Kind (Type, Constraint)

type  YesNo :: Type -> Constraint
class YesNo a where
  yesno :: a -> Bool

type    TruthyNum :: Type -> Type
newtype TruthyNum a = TruthyNum a

instance (Num a, Eq a) => YesNo (TruthyNum a) where
  yesno (TruthyNum 0) = False
  yesno _             = True

-- standalone deriving, is used when deriving an instance
-- outside of the data declaration
deriving via TruthyNum Int
  instance YesNo Int
deriving via TruthyNum Integer
  instance YesNo Integer
deriving via TruthyNum Float
  instance YesNo Float
```

`Applicative` lifting is another behavour that overlaps in this way. Given `Applicative f` you can lift algebras like

- `Semigroup a`, `Monoid a`, `Num a`

into

- `Semigroup (f a)`, `Monoid (f a)`, `Num (f a)`

```
instance (Applicative f, Num a) => Num (f a) where
  (+)         = liftA2 (+)
  (-)         = liftA2 (-)
  (*)         = liftA2 (*)
  negate      = liftA  . negate
  abs         = liftA  . abs
  signum      = liftA  . signum
  fromInteger = liftA0 . fromInteger where liftA0 = pure
```

Instead of writing an overlapping instance we make an instance of the [newtype `Ap f a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.3.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Ap).

```
type    Ap :: (k -> Type) -> (k -> Type)
newtype Ap f a = Ap (f a)
  deriving newtype (Functor, Applicative, ..)

instance (Applicative f, Num a) => Num (Ap @Type f a) where
  (+)         = liftA2 (+)
  (-)         = liftA2 (-)
  (*)         = liftA2 (*)
  negate      = liftA  . negate
  abs         = liftA  . abs
  signum      = liftA  . signum
  fromInteger = liftA0 . fromInteger where liftA0 = pure
```

Here is a trampoline example, that derives instances that depend on the previous derivation. The datatype is a "3D vector", but it's simply a datatype that has 3 arguments of the same type.

1. Built-in derivation of equality and a generic representation for `V3`
2. `Generically1` (a `newtype`) to derive `Applicative` using the generic representation from 1.
3. `Ap` to derive `Num` by lifting over `Applicative` from 2.
4. `TruthyNum` to derive `YesNo` using equality and that `Num` instance from 3.

The `Applicative` we derive involves lifting `pure a = V3 a a a` so when we write `0 :: V3 Int` we actually mean `V3 0 0 0 :: V3 Int`.

This means that your `YesNo` instance is implemented by comparing against `(/= V3 0 0 0)`. So we treat `V3` as "false" when the values are `0`.

```
-- >> 0 :: V3 Int
-- V3 0 0 0
-- >> yesno (V3 0 0 0)
-- False
-- >> yesno (V3 0 0 2)
-- True
data V3 a = V3 a a a
  deriving
  stock (Eq, Show, Generic1)

  deriving (Functor, Applicative)
  via Generically1 V3

  deriving (Semigroup, Monoid, Num)
  via Ap V3 a

  deriving YesNo
  via TruthyNum (V3 a)
```