# "class TypeClassName a b where" is incorrect syntax?

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell and I am not quite sure whether `class TypeClassName a b where` is incorrect.

Does it make sense to write something like that in Haskell?

I know that `class TypeClassName a where` is correct but I am not sure whether the extra `b` would make any sense there ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with Multi-parameter type class extension enabled.

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
```

Regarding it's usage and requirement, it actually depends upon your application. For example, in the [linked tutorial](https://www.fpcomplete.com/school/to-infinity-and-beyond/pick-of-the-week/type-families-and-pokemon) for type family they actually have to use this extension. Also, this [wikibook section](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Advanced_type_classes#Multi-parameter_type_classes) explains how it is used for `Collection` type class. For `Collection` typeclass, multi parameter type class makes good use case:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
 class Eq e => Collection c e where
     insert :: c -> e -> c
     member :: c -> e -> Bool
```

Here `c` is the collection type like List and `e` is the element inside the collection. So any collection which supports `insert` and memebership test function can be made instance of this typeclass.

Comment: Is that true that most of standard Haskell libraries do not use such MPTCs ?

Comment: @jhegedus I'm not sure whether standard Haskell libraries use it or not, but using MPTC is not a bad practice! (You can also see this answer by Don Stewart: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10849782/1651941 )