# Haskell show pair of string

Tags: haskell

How can I define an instance for showing (String, String) structure

```
instance Show (String, String) where
show (a, b) = show a ++ show b
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you'd used proper indentation, and switched on the altogether harmless `-XFlexibleInstances`

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
instance Show (String, String) where
  show (a, b) = show a ++ show b
```

then this instance would, in itself, work (you need to switch on `-XFlexibleInstances`). However, it won't compile because a strictly more general instance

```
instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (a, b) where
  show (a, b) = "(" ++ show a ++ "," ++ show b ++ ")"
```

is already defined in the prelude. If you're determined to override that one then you also need to switch on `-XOverlappingInstances`. But this one is not so harmless; in fact [it's evil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10845179/which-haskell-ghc-extensions-should-users-use-avoid/10849782?s=3|0.2587#10849782): overlapping instances can lead to all kinds of trouble, and for your specific definition the instance also doesn't comply with the requirement that `read . show ≡ id`.

Comment: I asked that to use the same syntax in a custom defined type, it worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that you can't without a bunch of language extensions that really are better suited to other tasks.

There is already an instance for `(Show a, Show b) => Show (a, b)`, meaning that defining it for `(String, String)` would overlap with the already existing one.  A better choice would be to write your own `showStrTuple` as

```
showStrTuple :: (String, String) -> String
showStrTuple (a, b) = show a ++ show b
```

Alternatively, if you *really* want to use `show` on it, make a newtype (which are designed for defining new typeclasses that would otherwise conflict with existing ones):

```
newtype StrTuple = StrTuple { unStrTuple :: (String, String) } deriving (Eq)

instance Show StrTuple where
    show (StrTuple (a, b)) = show a ++ show b
```

Then you just construct it with

```
show $ StrTuple ("hello", "world")
```

Comment: You are right, however, I asked this to use the knowledge on another type without puting many lines of code here